# Why CMakeLists's rosbuild_add_executable couldn't have a name 'test'?

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My package couldn't generate executable file when CMakeLists has a line:

```
  rosbuild_add_executable(test src/t.cpp)
```

My package can generate executable file when CMakeLists has a line:

```
  rosbuild_add_executable(test2 src/t.cpp)
```

I found that only the name 'test',it failed to generate an executable file.

What happened? I use ROS diamondback.

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11034/why-cmakelists%27s-rosbuild_add_executable-couldn%27t-have-a-name-%27test%27?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From [the rosbuild/ CMakeLists](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbuild/CMakeLists#Build_macros) wiki page:

> Do not call your executable test. This target name is reserved for unit testing, and CMake will fail if you try it

The page describes a workaround if you really need to call it `test`

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1